# pandas.dataframe.set_index(column1) in python to MATLAB

Tags: python, matlab, indexing

I want to index a table in MATLAB on a particular column. In Python we can use `set_index(column_name)` using pandas library. I want an equivalent code that can do in MATLAB. To be more precise I want to look at the internal code of `set_index()` in Python. Can someone help me?

Code in MATLAB:

```
T = readtable('filename.csv');
```

I want to set an index on `T.column_name` here.

Comment: Can you explain your question without using Python's terms?

Comment: MATLAB's tables do not utilize an index like Pandas' dataframes do. What exactly are you trying to accomplish?